# Split data between values of a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, split

I am looking to categorise some data I have. The data set contains the changelog behind a media campaign. I would like to have a Set-Up, In-Flight and Post-Flight

Example below:

```
Date of change | Change type
01/01/2021  Settings Change (4393)
02/01/2021  Settings Change (7490)
05/01/2021  Campaign set live
06/01/2021  Settings Change (6524)
07/01/2021  Settings Change (1321)
08/01/2021  Campaign paused
09/01/2021  Settings Change (8822)
11/01/2021  Settings Change (5891)
12/01/2021  Campaign Set live
13/01/2021  Settings Change (4669)
14/01/2021  Settings Change (2287)
15/01/2021  Campaign ends
16/01/2021  Settings Change (5649)
```

I would like to see something like:

```
Date of change | Change | Stage of change
01/01/2021  Settings Change (4393) Pre-Flight
02/01/2021  Settings Change (7490) Pre-Flight
05/01/2021  Campaign live          Campaign live
06/01/2021  Settings Change (6524) In-Flight
07/01/2021  Settings Change (1321) In-Flight
08/01/2021  Campaign paused        Campaign paused
09/01/2021  Settings Change (8822) In-Flight (Paused)
11/01/2021  Settings Change (5891) In-Flight (Paused)
12/01/2021  Campaign live          Campaign live
13/01/2021  Settings Change (4669) In-Flight
14/01/2021  Settings Change (2287) In-Flight
15/01/2021  Campaign ends          Campaign ends
16/01/2021  Settings Change (5649) Post-Flight
```

I have tried splitting based on a value but this is before or after a certain value or based on something like a date, not on the Change Type.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: what is the condition for ` Set-Up, In-Flight and Post-Flight`? Also, can you post a pandas dataframe that can be copied?

Comment: @Epsi95 `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+| \| ')` solves the latter issue for the input dataframe :)

Answer (score 2):

Let’s first normalize your `Change` column from your `Change type` row, in particular the `Campaign [Ss]et live` rows:

```
>>> df['Change'] = df['Change type'].str.replace('Campaign set live', 'Campaign live', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> df = df.drop(columns=['Change type'])
>>> df
   Date of change                  Change
0      01/01/2021  Settings Change (4393)
1      02/01/2021  Settings Change (7490)
2      05/01/2021           Campaign live
3      06/01/2021  Settings Change (6524)
4      07/01/2021  Settings Change (1321)
5      08/01/2021         Campaign paused
6      09/01/2021  Settings Change (8822)
7      11/01/2021  Settings Change (5891)
8      12/01/2021           Campaign live
9      13/01/2021  Settings Change (4669)
10     14/01/2021  Settings Change (2287)
11     15/01/2021           Campaign ends
12     16/01/2021  Settings Change (5649)
```

Then we basically want to keep the rows that define campaign states as-is, and fill them based on the previous values.

We can use the same dictionary for both things, respectively

1. defining the fill values (that we can then propagate with `fillna`), and
2. masking the rows where we don’t want this filled value to reset it to the origina `Change` column:

```
>>> state_after_change = {
...     'Campaign live': 'In-Flight',
...     'Campaign paused': 'In-Flight (Paused)',
...     'Campaign ends': 'Post-Flight'
... }
>>> df['State of change'] = df['Change'].map(state_after_change).ffill().fillna('Pre-flight')
>>> df['State of change']
0             Pre-flight
1             Pre-flight
2              In-Flight
3              In-Flight
4              In-Flight
5     In-Flight (Paused)
6     In-Flight (Paused)
7     In-Flight (Paused)
8              In-Flight
9              In-Flight
10             In-Flight
11           Post-Flight
12           Post-Flight
Name: State of change, dtype: object
>>> df['State of change'] = df['State of change'].mask(df['Change'].isin(state_after_change), df['Change'])
>>> df
   Date of change                  Change     State of change
0      01/01/2021  Settings Change (4393)          Pre-flight
1      02/01/2021  Settings Change (7490)          Pre-flight
2      05/01/2021           Campaign live       Campaign live
3      06/01/2021  Settings Change (6524)           In-Flight
4      07/01/2021  Settings Change (1321)           In-Flight
5      08/01/2021         Campaign paused     Campaign paused
6      09/01/2021  Settings Change (8822)  In-Flight (Paused)
7      11/01/2021  Settings Change (5891)  In-Flight (Paused)
8      12/01/2021           Campaign live       Campaign live
9      13/01/2021  Settings Change (4669)           In-Flight
10     14/01/2021  Settings Change (2287)           In-Flight
11     15/01/2021           Campaign ends       Campaign ends
12     16/01/2021  Settings Change (5649)         Post-Flight
```